# API errors out if I try to look up an order or payment that is completed. How can I get a definitive status of a payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have the following flow with Paypal:

1. I create a payment with intent "order", and I redirect the user to Paypal's website.
2. Once the user returns, I execute the payment.
3. Then, I authorize the order.

At this point, I can still look up the payment or the order and I get expected result.

4. Finally, I capture the order.

After I capture the order, I can't lookup the payment with /v1/payments/payment/PAY-XYZ or retrieve the order with /v1/payments/orders/O-ABC. I get a 500 Internal Service Error.

**Before you tell me to send debug id to Paypal because I stumbled upon their bug**: I tried, but they are not responding. I had them on the phone, sent support requests, etc. I got no reply from them, so I have to turn to community.

After capture, I can still lookup a payment by listing payment resources. Since I store paypal's create time, I send a GET request that looks like:

/v1/payments/payment?start_time=2016-06-21T09:08:56Z&end_time=2016-06-21T09:08:58Z

Sure enough, I can get the payment object back, but that looks awfully hacky to me.

The reason why I need the entire payment object is because I need a definitive information about the status of the payment. E.g. I can stumble upon a network error when I send a capture request and I won't get capture ID, so I can't check what's going on. Or I can miss a webhook event (for any reason, e.g. bug in my code), and the payment can become refunded without me knowing, so it would be ver nice to be able to fetch a payment.

I noticed the REST API documentation here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_get says that I should use that endpoint for incomplete payments, but I don't understand why I can't check the order, or why list payment resources works, but fetching a single payment doesn't.

Retrieving the payment used to work though, so I could look up related_resources of transactions of the response (like I can do now with listing all payments by date).

My question is: what is the recommended way to get the definitive information about a payment?

Also, if someone from Paypal is reading this, here are some debug_id's so you can perhaps look into it: 3ffa3007a7561 (result of https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/orders/O-3PA36862ST053572T) or 85576d66784cd (response from https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-7N237030X85089344K5UQIKI)

This happens on both sandbox and live.

Thanks,
Dejan